# Can't understand arguments of Count function in MS Excel

Tags: excel

I have a function as follows in my Excel file: =COUNT(4:4)

I really can't understand what do its arguments mean, since they must be a range of cells, for example A4:D4 or A4:B44, but two numbers (especially the same!) don't make to mush sense for me.

Maybe this question is elementary and may collect a lot of down votes, but I haven't find any explanation about such kind of cell range format in documentation.

Comment: Think of it as `=COUNT(A4:XFD4)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how you reference an entire row. If you click a row label when Excel is waiting for a range reference, that is what you get. So that is counting all numeric cells in row 4.

Similarly, an entire column can be referenced by e.g. `B:B`.